# Error when creating or updating mamba environment

Tags: conda, virtual-environment, mamba

I get an error (see snippet below) when creating or updating an environment with mamba that has to do with an utf-8 decodification. Not sure where that happens, but in the log I see some lines refer to cache. I therefore tried to execute `mamba clean --all` to clean everything, but even that command fails with the same error.

Does this mean mamba is broken in some way? Reinstalling is not an option as I don't have the permission to do it in the machine I'm working on. What else can I do? For reference, [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9744) I found a github issue in conda that states my exact same problem, but unfortunately no answers were posted.

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 78, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 154, in execute
    result[installer_type] = installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/mamba_env.py", line 173, in mamba_install
    handle_txn(conda_transaction, prefix, args, True)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mamba/linking.py", line 38, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.download_and_extract()
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 205, in download_and_extract
    self._pfe.execute()
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 707, in execute
    self.prepare()
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 686, in prepare
    self.paired_actions.update(
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 687, in <genexpr>
    (prec, self.make_actions_for_record(prec)) for prec in self.link_precs
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 554, in make_actions_for_record
    extracted_pcrec = next(
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 555, in <genexpr>
    (
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 558, in <genexpr>
    PackageCacheData(pkgs_dir).query(pref_or_spec)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 82, in __call__
    package_cache_instance = super().__call__(pkgs_dir)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 95, in __init__
    self._urls_data = UrlsData(pkgs_dir)
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 489, in __init__
    self._urls_data = [line.strip().decode("utf-8") for line in fh]
  File "/path/to/mamba/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 489, in <listcomp>
    self._urls_data = [line.strip().decode("utf-8") for line in fh]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 1: invalid start byte

`$ /path/to/mamba/bin/mamba create -n <NAME> -f <FILE>`
```

EDIT: Output of `mamba info`

```
active environment : base
    active env location : <PRIVATE>/mamba
            shell level : 3
       user config file : <PRIVATE>/.condarc
 populated config files : <PRIVATE>/.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.9.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __glibc=2.17=0
                          __linux=3.10.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : <PRIVATE>/mamba  (read only)
      conda av data dir : <PRIVATE>/mamba/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
                          <PRIVATE>
          package cache : <PRIVATE>/.conda/pkgs
                          <PRIVATE>/miniconda3/pkgs
       envs directories : <PRIVATE>/.conda/envs
                          <PRIVATE>/conda_envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.2 CPython/3.10.9 Linux/3.10.0-1160.95.1.el7.x86_64 rhel/7.9 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 688555:688555
             netrc file : <PRIVATE>/.netrc
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Please also provide the exact command that produces the error.
You say it happens when creating or updating an environment, so please privde the commands you tried for creation and for update.
Is it a pure mamba installation, or a mixed conda with mamab insatllation?
Provide the output of `mamba info` (you may remove all lines that show your local directory names)

Comment: @maddes8cht The command is exactly the one at the end of the log: ` /path/to/mamba/bin/mamba create -n <NAME> -f <FILE>`. I added the output of mamba info as well.

Comment: you tried to call mamba by using a command like  ` /path/to/mamba/bin/mamba` ? Of course your path should be different?
And maybe you call mamba yust by calling `mamba` ? And then, you will have provided a real env name instead of <NAME> and a real file instead of <FILE> ?
The outpu tof mamba info was just by using `mamba info` , not ` /path/to/mamba/bin/mamba info` ?

Comment: @maddes8cht Of course everything I referred to as /path/to/mamba, <PRIVATE>, <FILE> and <NAME> is just fictitious and in the code I have real values. I though that was obvious.

Comment: never mind, at times it gets astonishing what people actually do a commandline -so just asking ;)
Are there any unicode or special caharacters in the actual `<NAME >` or `<FILE>` names, or inside of the `<FILE>` ?

Was the content of the `<FILE>` exported on the same machine?
Does it have the proper line endings for your machine?

Comment: talking of permissions:
So you don't have permissions on the mamba installation, but on your own environments?

Which also may mean: You have permission on your own environmants, but not on base?

Comment: Are there any working environments except base that you can use?
This seems to be more of a kind of permission problem

Comment: Just wondering about the shell level of 3:
As this seems to be a kind of permission problem: Maybe first shell out of these three levels?
I'm not exactly sure what mamba counts as a shell level, at least its several mamba activates on top of each other. So deactivate them until you are only in your base. Mamba should even work without being in  any conda environment at all, as long as it can find the necessary files. Maybe in the depths of multiple shell levels, something got stuck with the permissions setup?

Comment: @maddes8cht There are no weird, non-utf8 characters in any of those files. Actually, I even tried to run myself the piece of code `[line.strip().decode("utf-8") for line in fh]` through a console and it didn't raise any error. To answer your other question, I don't have permissions on the mamba installation but I'm free to do everything with my own environments.

Comment: @maddes8cht And yes, I even tried deactivating 3 times and reactivate mamba, but nothing changed

Comment: So again:
Are there any existing mamba environments that are working for you?
Are there other people using that mamba installation? Are they facing the same problems or not?

Comment: Yes there are more than a few, just now I need to update one of them (or re-create, as I tried to do) and I can't do it because of this error

Comment: I would guess thee is something broken with the cache of your main mamba insatll.
I guess there will be no solution without further help from your administrator. Maybe  he should do that `mamba clean --all` or otherwise repair that installation.
If you are not the only person using this mamba install, others may  get the same problem too.